# Is MaxQ' sum of all possible rewards or highest possible reward?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm coding a simple q-learning example and to update q-values you need a maxQ'.

I'm not sure if maxQ' is referring to the sum of all possible rewards or the highest possible reward:

[image]

Comment: Please put *all* relevant information *in* the question. *Not* behind external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is maximum `Q-values` among all possible actions for the state `s'`. Basically, you need to take a `max` over all `Q(s',a')` for all valid actions `a'` in state `s'`.